# open data in maintenance and repair

Tags: data-request, industry

I want an open dataset in maintenance and repair of factory machines including the following fields:

- Equipment Code
- Equipment Name
- Service Code
- Service Name
- Service Description
- Workorder Date
- Workorder Number
- Workorder  Type (preventive/Emergency)
- Workorder Start
- Workorder Finish

Does anybody know one?

Comment: What you want is example data, right? For instance data for 1 day in a single factory?

Comment: yes, in addition I prefer an open dataset so that I can use and refer to it freely.

Answer (score 4):

I found this link:
[Predictive Maintainance and Sensor Data Analytics](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/predictive-maintainance-sensor-data-analytics-ambarish-ganguly?trk=hp-feed-article-title-like)

> Data from a semi-conductor manufacturing process
>
> Key facts: Data Structure: The data consists of 2 files the dataset file SECOM consisting of 1567 examples each with 591 features a 1567 x 591 matrix and a labels file containing the classifications and date time stamp for each example.

Answer (score 2):

IBM has a product called maximo. They have a demo web site that has demo data.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499350

You want to log in, then from the go to menu select assets > assets